# How can I make sure Android Beam doesn't start a new instance of my 'singleTop' activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, android-beam

First, the use case : 2 phones have my app opened on the same screen. I want one user to be able to share the screen content (data) with the other one without necessarily opening a new instance of the activity when beaming using NFC.
(both Android devices are running Ice Cream Sandwich)

So I have a **singleTop** activity declared like this in the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:launchMode="singleTop">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/activityLabel">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="a.b.c/x.y.z" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/x.y.z"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When a `VIEW` action is fired and the activity is already on top, the `onNewIntent()` method is called in the **same** instance if the activity.

When a `NDEF_DISCOVERED` action is fired and the activity is already on top, the `onCreate()` method is called in a **new** instance of the activity.

Answer (score 4):

You describe the case that the app is already open and the proper Activity is in the foreground. In that case, you can make use of the foreground-dispatching of NFC intents by calling [`NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.content.IntentFilter%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%5B%5D%29) in your Activity's `onResume()` (and [`disableForegroudDispatch()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#disableForegroundDispatch%28android.app.Activity%29) in `onPause()`). This will force all NFC Intents to be delivered to your Activity (via `onNewIntent()`).

Comment: This looks like the way to go but I don't have a 2nd NFC-capable device to test it out now.

Doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch

Comment: Using an NFC tag with an NDEF message would give virtually the same result as receiving data via Android Beam. Perhaps you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you. But I have a workaround: have the NDEF_DISCOVERED start a new activity. Make that activity invisible (`Theme.NoBackground`) and in the onCreate, make it start the `MyActivity` with singleTop and finish immediately. `MyActivity` should now appear with `onNewIntent`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Android Beam sample:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AndroidBeamDemo/index.html

It implements this behavior that you want (minus VIEW intent filtering). I'm not sure if that intent will affect the NDEF_DISCOVERED one, but it would be interesting to maybe modify the Android Beam sample to see if you can cause the same behavior as your app.

Comment: I looked at the Android Beam sample (started by this actually) and it doesn't implement the foreground dispatching that I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: android:launchMode="singleInstance"
Works for me.

Comment: launchMode "singleInstance" is only for home screen replacements. In my case "singleTask" worked perfectly.