# New program instance created when NFC Tag tapped

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

My Android application is using an intent-filter on the event “NDEF_DISCOVERED” to get opened if it contains a certain URL.
It works fine but I have noticed that, if I put my application in background and tap a NFC Tag, **a new instance of the program is started**. If I do that a few times, I get several instances of my application created. This is causing me some problems so I would like to find a solution so that only one instance gets opened.

A side comment: When my program is in foreground, I’m using enableForegroundDispatch() in onResume and disableForegroundDispatch() in onPause. It works fine.

When my program is in background and when I tap an NFC Tag, is there a way that the system detects that the program is already started and put it in foreground instead of starting a new instance?

As a matter of comparison, if I put my program in background, go to the list of programs and click on my program, Android detects that this program is already opened and resume it without creating a new instance (onCreate() of MainActivity is not called in that case). Why don’t we have the same behavior with NFC events and is it possible to have the same behavior?

I have read this thread ([Application receiving NFC always pops up new instance in front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702519/application-receiving-nfc-always-pops-up-new-instance-in-front) ) which is the same question but it didn’t help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451687/start-activity-with-nfc-in-a-specific-task) and it works indeed.

As the documentation says: (Source https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

> "singleTask" :
>
> The system creates a new task and instantiates the
> activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the
> activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the
> intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent()
> method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the
> activity can exist at a time.